# Filter useContext state in a component without changing global state

Tags: reactjs, use-state, state-management, react-state-management, react-context

I have a component that uses `useContext` to retrieve the global state, which is a list of movies/TV shows. I'm trying to save this global state into local state so I can filter the list by media type (movie or TV show) on a button click, but the filter should be reflected only locally, without dispatching an action to change the global state (I don't want the complete list to be lost).

However, after storing the global state to the local state, the local state is empty. Here is the component's code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { WatchListContext } from "../../contexts/WatchListProvider";

import WatchItem from "../WatchItem";

const WatchList = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(WatchListContext);
  const [watchList, setWatchList] = useState(state);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setWatchList((previousWatchlist) => {
      const filteredWatchList = previousWatchlist.filter(
        (watchItem) => watchItem.media_type === filter
      );

      return filteredWatchList;
    });
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter("tv")}>TV</button>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter("movie")}>MOVIES</button>
      </div>

      {watchList
        .filter((watchItem) => watchItem.media_type === filter)
        .map(({ id, title, overview, poster_url, release_date, genres }) => (
          <WatchItem
            key={id}
            title={title}
            overview={overview}
            poster_url={poster_url}
            release_date={release_date}
            genres={genres}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WatchList;
```

I can't understand why this isn't working. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't straightaway ties your `global state` with your `local state` like the way you did (`const [watchList, setWatchList] = useState(state);`):-

- by doing this it will automatically ties with your `default` value of your `state` declared in `context` which always gonna be an **empty** `array` or `[]` . So to go around this, why don't you `track` the incoming **changes** of `state` with `useEffect`, like so:-
- `WatchList.js`:-

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { WatchListContext } from "../../contexts/WatchListProvider";

import WatchItem from "../WatchItem";

const WatchList = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(WatchListContext);
  const [watchList, setWatchList] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  // handle fetching current changes of state received by Context
  useEffect(() => {
    (() => setWatchList(state))()
  }, [state])  

  // handle filtering of data
  useEffect(() => {
    setWatchList((previousWatchlist) => {
      const filteredWatchList = previousWatchlist.filter(
        (watchItem) => watchItem.media_type === filter
      );

      return filteredWatchList;
    });
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter("tv")}>TV</button>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter("movie")}>MOVIES</button>
      </div>

      {watchList
        .filter((watchItem) => watchItem.media_type === filter)
        .map(({ id, title, overview, poster_url, release_date, genres }) => (
          <WatchItem
            key={id}
            title={title}
            overview={overview}
            poster_url={poster_url}
            release_date={release_date}
            genres={genres}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WatchList;
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion solved the particular problem, but also made me realize there were other issues with the logic, which needed further refactoring.

Comment: Glad to help then